# trying to webscrape an ecom with selenium and python no output no error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hi i been trying to webscrape and exporting it as json. My code running without an error but still no output can someone please help I can't really figure it out. I'm using the selenium 4.8.2 even  my webdriver opens up but the error still persistl. I tries to fiddle with some solutions available on stackoverflow but no use.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json
import pandas as pd
import time

# create a new Chrome browser instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.minimize_window()

# load the page
url = "https://www.meesho.com/crepe-kurtis/p/156p4t"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(15)

# find all divs with class="sc-bcXHqe ergypN NewProductCardstyled__CardStyled-sc-6y2tys-0 ccpfUL NewProductCardstyled__CardStyled-sc-6y2tys-0 ccpfUL"
divs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='sc-bcXHqe ergypN NewProductCardstyled__CardStyled-sc-6y2tys-0 ccpfUL NewProductCardstyled__CardStyled-sc-6y2tys-0 ccpfUL']")

# loop over the divs and extract the product information
product_info = []
for div in divs:
    # try to find the product title
    try:
        p = div.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//p[@class='sc-dkrFOg bBOVfv NewProductCardstyled__StyledDesktopProductTitle-sc-6y2tys-5 ejhQZU NewProductCardstyled__StyledDesktopProductTitle-sc-6y2tys-5 ejhQZU']")
        title = p.text
    except:
        title = ''
    
    # try to find the product price
    try:
        h5 = div.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//h5[@class='sc-dkrFOg iIAyXW']")
        price = h5.text
    except:
        price = ''
    
    # try to find the product rating
    try:
        span = div.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//span[@class='sc-dkrFOg eXFtxl']")
        rating = span.text
    except:
        rating = ''
    
    # add the product information to the list
    product_info.append({
        'title': title,
        'price': price,
        'rating': rating
    })

# write the product information to a file named "data.json"
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(product_info, f)
    
# close the browser
driver.quit()
```

I even tried to output using print() but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

one of the problems with your code is you are using *.text* on *find_elements* which means you are finding the text attribute from a list which should not be the case. You can try find_element instead.

Refer here for example :

```
span = div.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='sc-dkrFOg eXFtxl']")
```